# No awakening without a Buddha?

Tags: arahant

> Worth keeping in mind is that an arahant needs to learn from a Buddha to become enlightened, so if the story in question means the prince became an Arahant (*epic for one awakened*) before meeting the Buddha, that is impossible.

Was said by monk [yuttadhammo](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/31976)

My person would reject such a categorical statement but is of course open to give it a prove.

No doubt that an awakened would seek out for the Sangha, but especially this days, although the Dhamma might be traceable, such as the Sangha is not sure.

So what is actually told about the appearances of a Paccecabuddha and Awakened, (such a person) being told as even someone who may be in the position to rebuke the monks?

*(Note that this is not given for entertaining, stacks, exchange and trade but as a tiny door out of the wheel of householding)*

Answer (score 3):

Page 18 of

[The Paccekabuddha:

A Buddhist Ascetic

A Study of the Concept of the Paccekabuddha

in Pali Canonical and Commentarial Literature](https://what-buddha-said.net/library/Wheels/wh305.pdf)

> **II. I. The Period In Which No Buddha Exists**
>
> Paccekabuddhas are said to exist only in periods when there are no Buddhas. “A person realises
> Paccekabodhi only when reborn at a time when there is no Buddha” (S-a III 189 and 208). Other
> expressions to denote this period are: ”the time which lies between (the appearances of) a Lord”
> (A-a I 194); ”a period in which no Teacher has appeared” (Pv-a III 144); and “the period between
> the Buddha (-periods)” (A-a II 192). One of the main characteristics of the Paccekabuddha’s
> career is that he attains insight during such a period.

I think this period is also called a [sasana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9A%C4%81sana):

> Śāsana may also refer to the 5000-year dispensation of a particular Buddha. That is, we are living in the śāsana of the Śakyamuni Buddha.

I that this doctrine is saying that that a paccekabuddha wouldn't exist during a time when the sammā sambuddha was teaching (and afterwards when his dhamma hadn't yet been forgotten).